# how to handle Invalid time zone with BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, datetime-format, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm working with a BigQuery table where I got date ingested as string originally generated by the Javascript method `Date();`. This is what my field looks like:

```
Sat Aug 05 2023 15:15:04 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Sat Aug 05 2023 14:30:40 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Sat Aug 05 2023 11:22:54 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)   
Sat Aug 05 2023 00:25:04 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
Sat Aug 05 2023 15:31:33 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)   
Sat Aug 05 2023 15:04:36 GMT-0700 (hora de verano del Pacífico)
etc...
```

As you can see I have all kind of different timezone here between parenthesis. How can I handle this? I need to convert these as unix seconds.

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%a  %b  %d %Y %X GMT%z", 'Sat Aug 05 2023 15:15:04 GMT-0700 (PDT)') AS x
```

I'm able to parse the first part of the string but I'm not sure how to handle the timezone part. Do I need to build a lookup table myself to handle all the scenarios?

#edit 1

Is this considered as a best practice to store the timezone in a different column? So even when applying PARSE_TIMESTAMP() I can always convert back the time using this column?

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns this: 2023-08-05 22:15:04 UTC

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%a  %b  %d %Y %X GMT%z", 'Sat Aug 05 2023 15:15:04 GMT-0700')
```

then you can turn this to unix seconds and see the result: 1691273704

```
SELECT UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%a  %b  %d %Y %X GMT%z", 'Sat Aug 05 2023 15:15:04 GMT-0700'))
```

Remove the custom values in brackets in the end like 'PDT', and dont forget to add a bracket for unix_seconds as well.

Comment: thanks. I've edited my answer and added the missing bracket. I've also removed the  unix second part because this is actually unnecessary. Now what you are suggested is to remove the timezone entirely. If I'm doing that I won't be able to convert it back to the timezone initially recorded. I'd like `PARSE_TIMESTAMP()` to not convert into UTC... if that make sense

Comment: the name of the timezone is really not important, whatever its offset from UTC, you can just specify it using its distance from UTC, and its the end same with the timezone. see here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timezone_definitions

If you insist on the timezone as an argument to function. you can use the timezone argument like this:

SELECT DATETIME(CAST('2016-10-24 15:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP), "America/Los_Angeles")

this returns 2016-10-24T08:00:00. I always offset from UTC and dont bother with timezone, that is the standard as well.

Comment: And if you need to specify the timezone at the end for other purposes, then you can just append to it like you append to a string, because in bigquery timestamps are stored in UTC.

Comment: SELECT DATETIME(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%a  %b  %d %Y %X GMT%z", 'Sat Aug 05 2023 15:15:04 GMT-0700'), "Europe/Warsaw") 

Here I take your GMT -0700 and convert it to Warsaw timezone. At the end of the result GMT is not specified, if thats what you are asking for.